# Reading file line by line iteration issue

Tags: perl, file, for-loop

I have the following simple piece of code (identified as the problem piece of code and extracted from a much larger program).

Is it me or can you see an obvious error in this code that it stopping it from matching against `$variable` and printing `$found` when it definitely should be doing?

Nothing is printed when I try to print `$variable`, and there are definitely matching lines in the file I am using.

**The code:**

```
if (defined $var) {
    open (MESSAGES, "<$messages") or die $!;
    my $theText = $mech->content( format => 'text' );
    print "$theText\n";
    foreach  my $variable  (<MESSAGES>) {
        chomp ($variable);
        print "$variable\n";
        if ($theText =~ m/$variable/) {
            print "FOUND\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I have located this as the point at which the error is occurring but cannot understand why?
There may be something I am totally overlooking as its very late?

Comment: Is `$theText` being printed?

Comment: Yes the content from the webpage is being printed and I know that the string in my text file is found in the content as I hard coded the string in the pattern match and it found it in the content

Comment: You should try reading the file into an array, like `my @messages = <MESSAGES>` and you can then `print scalar @messages` to see how many lines have been read. I think it is most likely you are picking up the wrong file, either because `$messages` doesn't contain what you think it does or because it is looking in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** I have since realised that I misread your question and this probably doesn't solve the problem. However the points are valid so I am leaving them here.

You probably have regular expression metacharacters in `$variable`. The line

```
if ($theText =~ m/$variable/) { ... }
```

should be

```
if ($theText =~ m/\Q$variable/) { ... }
```

to escape any that there are.

But are you sure you don't just want `eq`?

In addition, you should read from the file using

```
while (my $variable = <MESSAGES>) { ... }
```

as a `for` loop will unnecessarily read the entire file into memory. And *please* use a better name than `$variable`.

Comment: thanks for the point about using `while`. I do normally, i was just trying anything to get the code to work in this case, thanks for your help.

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.. Am I missing the question at hand? You're just trying to match "$theText" to anything on each line in the file right?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $fh;
my $filename = $ARGV[0] or die "$0 filename\n";

open $fh, "<", $filename;
my $match_text = "whatever";
my $matched = '';

# I would use a while loop, out of habit here
#while(my $line = <$fh>) {
foreach my $line (<$fh>) {
    $matched = 
        $line =~ m/$match_text/ ? "Matched" : "Not matched";

    print $matched . ": " . $line;
}

close $fh

./test.pl testfile
Not matched: this is some textfile
Matched: with a bunch of lines or whatever and
Not matched: whatnot....
```

Edit: Ah, I see.. Why don't you try printing before and after the "chomp()" and see what you get? That shouldn't be the issue, but it doesn't hurt to test each case..

Comment: +1: It would be a good idea to check that the open succeeded, but the three-argument `open` and the lexical file handles are good.  Nominally, you should close that which you open.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Right, *always* close the files you open. I always close them in the same scope it was opened in.

Comment: FYI: I said 'nominally' because if you use `open my $fh, '<', $filename`, or an equivalent such as in your code, Perl closes the file automatically when the variable goes out of scope.  See the information at the very end of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) in the Perl documentation.  I tend to put the explicit close in, but I've been programming with Perl for (shudder) more than 20 years, and for some of that time it was necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Oh nice. I did not know that, thanks. Here's the last bit from perldoc -f open "Using the constructor from the "IO::Handle" package (or one of its subclasses, such as "IO::File" or "IO::Socket"), you can generate anonymous filehandles that have the scope of whatever variables hold references to them, and automatically close whenever and however you leave that scope:". I'll stick with explicitly closing the handles. I can see some nasty bugs if one gets it wrong.

Comment: @chrsblck: That document is a little misleading, as a simple `open my $fh, '<', 'filename'` will *autovivify* such a file handle without any mention of a module, and that is accepted best practice in modern Perl. File handles opened like that will normally be destroyed (and so implicitly closed) when they go out of scope at the end of the enclosing block. That is generally fine for input file-handles, but you will probably want to close output file handles explicitly and check that it was successful, otherwise you may incur silent data loss.